# High-efficiency blinking LED circuit

Tags: led, battery-operated, efficiency, blink

I'm an artist currently working on an installation piece that requires a little more engineering knowledge than I possess. In short, what I'd like to achieve is a 2 LED blinking circuit with battery efficiency in mind. Preferably fresh batteries should last for a few months to a year or better. I'm guessing the best way would be with two layers of blinking: one blink would be more of a high frequency strobe and just appear "on," the other would cycle the LEDs off and on every second.

I don't know where to start with this, let alone if I'm headed in the right direction. Am I?  What frequency would be best for the strobe? Again efficiency is the priority. I don't mind if there's a slight flicker like a GFI switch indicator. Any advice that will get me moving is appreciated.

Comment: The flicker rate and on/off duty cycle is determined solely by your requirements but you are a bit vague on this. Also are both leds as one i.e. on/off simultaneously?

Comment: What about a joule theif?  http://www.r3uk.com/index.php/tech-tips/43-electrical-tomfoolery/203-the-joule-thief-flasher

Comment: Have you considered topping up the batteries using solar power? - see http://www.evilmadscientist.com/2008/simple-solar-circuits/

Comment: Please describe the blinking pattern required in more detail. It should be possible to take your description and implement a solution such that you can say "Yes - just what I wanted". And NOT "Not bad, but I really wanted ..." | Also, how bright do you want it and what sot of battery size is acceptable. | I long ago implemented an LED flasher that ran for something in the 5 to 10 year range. That's extreme but it's essentially "just a matter of design" and not overly hard to do if you know the REAL spec.

Comment: I'd be happy to add an answer IF what was here by then was not good enough (but it probably will be) IF I knew what was really needed. So far it's not certain.

Comment: @SomeHardwareGuy that looks interesting and similar to what I had in mind but obviously more in-depth. I will enjoy reading this. Thank you.

Comment: @JImDearden That would be an awesome idea but eventually this thing will be stored in a room that doesn't exist yet and I don't know if there will be any natural light.

Comment: Don't dismiss the idea too quickly, there are lots of other ways of harvesting energy from the environment apart from 'solar power' (which also works under a normal light bulb btw). (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_harvesting) Perhaps you should look into that and make it part of the work or perhaps a series of work.

Comment: Most of the shop displays I see with blinking LEDs use very short and bright blinks to maximise the battery.

Answer (score 4):

First off, your high-frequency flashing will give (at best) only a slight improvement in battery lifetime. The idea is that you can increase efficiency by driving the LED at a higher current, and while this is true for some LEDs, it's not true for all.

That said, getting a year out of a continuously flashing LED will take a rather large battery. Let's say that you're flashing the LED with a 25% duty cycle: that is, only on for 25% of the time. And furthermore, let's say that you are running the LED at 10 mA. Then (obviously) in one hour the LED will be on for 15 minutes. The total current drawn will be 10 mA x 0.25 hours, or 2.5 mA-hr. In one day, the total current drawn will be 2.5 x 24, or 60 mA-hr. After one month, it will be 60 x 30, or 1800 mA-hr.

Now for batteries. You can get rechargeable NIMH D cells that will give you 10 - 12 A-hrs of service, so you might think to get a year at lower current drains. However, http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/nickelmetalhydride_appman.pdf suggests that NIMH will self-discharge by 20 - 50% in 6 months, so that pretty much sets that limit.

A bog-standard alkaline D cell will have http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/e95.pdf a capacity of ~ 18 - 20 A-hr and in this application you'd think would give you about 10 months to a year. The problem here is that the lifetime is specified to the point that the battery voltage is 1/2 that of a fresh battery, and LEDs have a minimum voltage that they need.

So, what you want to do is "possible", but only if you can accept the battery size.

What you need to do is get some high-brightness LEDs, a cheap power supply, a DMM and some resistors, and experiment with the LEDs. Find the current level that gives you the brightness you need, keeping in mind that your installation may (or may not, you just have to think about it) be seen in bright light which will require more LED current to appear bright enough. Once you have a target current, only then can you start grinding out the numbers which will tell you how much battery you need.

For example, let's say you have 2 LEDs in series, and they draw 10 mA when on, and their forward voltage is 2 volts each. The LEDs will need 4 volts total. If you use alkaline D cells you can put 6 in series to get 9 volts, and at the end of life they will be putting out about 4.8 volts, giving you about 0.8 volts margin for your current control element. Assuming 20 A-hr for the cells, you'll get about 11 months.

Is that too big a battery? Well, there are other alternatives. For this long-duration application, http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/elevating_self_discharge indicates that rechargeable lithium cells (lithium-ion) are possible. http://www.electricwingman.com/power/a123-loose-cells.aspx has a single 20 A-hr cell. Note its size and weight.

Primary lithiums are also a good technical choice. http://www.onlybatteries.com/showitem.asp?ItemID=14509&vfpr=10.30&vfbr=Blue+Sleeve&vfcat=Electronics+Electronics+Accessories+Power+Batteries&vfsku=14509&vfbi=no_bid&sid=gpla&vfsku=14509&vfsku=14509&gpla=pla&gclid=CjwKEAjwuoOpBRCSy6yQm66J1g8SJABrXW48PiokBnHnnAVNcptv7FH19wDGumSYhbMnC9kQH9-IQxoCevPw_wcB is an example, and you could get away with one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way of driving a LED is to switch it in series with a resistor. The resistor limits the current through the LED.

Lets say the voltage is *V*, resistance *R*, and LED forward voltage *Vf*.

The current drawn is then *(V-Vf)/R*

All that remains is to get the battery data sheet and see how long the battery will last at that current.

**Pulsing**

If you pulse the LED, the current drawn is a fraction of this according to the duty cycle. So for example, for a particular resistance with the LED on all the time, roughly the same current is drawn by using half the resistance with a 50% duty cycle.

Now, which is brighter? Constant current, or PWM with a higher current? [This thread](http://www.candlepowerforums.com/vb/showthread.php?70073-Constant-Current-vs-PWM-dimming-Revealed) suggests that constant current is more efficient, although it is for very bright LEDs.

**Ideas**

Any efficiency though is minor compared to the choice of LED. You have to choose one that has high brightness for a given current. Different colours in the same LED class also have different maximum brightnesses. To increase perceived brightness, and thus require less current, you could choose a LED with a narrow angle of emittance.

Also if you use a boost (step-up) or buck (step-down) DC-DC converter, you can supply a constant voltage to the LED circuit while drawing the battery down, thus maintaining brightness.

Comment: all very helpful. thank you. it's a little over my head in a couple places so i'm not sure how to respond with more informed questions but it definitely helps me know what to research. much oblidged.

Answer (score 1):

For the low frequency flash you can use a 3909 chip and flash an LED for more than a year from a single penlight battery (done this many times).  It was specifically made for long duration low current draw LED flashing.  All you need is the chip, a single capacitor, and 4 connections.  (One of the easiest flashers ever made.)  Though the chip is no longer made, you can find it surplus with a quick google.  The downside is that the flash duration is very brief.  So, if you need your LED to stay on for a long time with each flash, then there are better choices (cmos version of a 555).  Anecdotally, and it might be of use to you...  I bought a fake alarm keypad from Harbor freight for about $5.  It has a built in 2 led flasher (red and green).  It has been flashing on two penlight batteries on my porch for over 3 years, and is flashing today...  I'm a bit midboggled by this.  Good luck.